# batch file message keeps looping

Tags: batch-file

First let me say I am not a programmer. Someone else wrote this batch file for me and it worked great before. Last time I was on Windows 7 and now I am on Windows 10. I have updated it with new file path and names. When I run batch file it starts normal, then after initializing the first setup.exe I get a message in the dos window

```
C:\>tasklist /fi "imagename eq setup.exe"   | find ":"  1>nul

C:\>if 1 == 1 goto loop
```

It keeps repeating those 2 lines. The batch file runs the installation successfully. I was just wondering how I stop those lines from scrolling down the screen.

```
SET C3Dsrc=\\C221A-ADK\CAD_Deploy\Autodesk\2020\AEC_2020_Civil3D\Img
SET NavMansrc=\\C221A-ADK\CAD_Deploy\Autodesk\2020\AEC_2020_NavisManage\Img
SET Recapsrc=\\C221A-ADK\CAD_Deploy\Autodesk\2020\AEC_2020_ReCapPro\Img
SET RasDessrc=\\C221A-ADK\CAD_Deploy\Autodesk\2020\AEC_2020_RasterDes\Img
SET VehTrksrc=\\C221A-ADK\CAD_Deploy\Autodesk\2020\AEC_2020_Vehicle\Img
SET Addonsrc=\\C221A-ADK\CAD_Deploy\Autodesk\2020\2020_AddOns
SET scriptsrc=\\C221A-ADK\CAD_Deploy\Autodesk\2020\Post_Install
SET updatesrc=\\C221A-ADK\CAD_Deploy\Autodesk\2020\2020_Updates

echo Deleting local temp files...
DEL %tmp%\*.* /F /S /Q

echo Installing Civil 3D 2020...Please wait...Install takes approx 60 minutes...
SET target=NAVMAN
START /WAIT %C3Dsrc%\setup.exe /qb /I %C3Dsrc%\AEC_2020_Civil3D.ini
goto LOOP

:LOOP
tasklist /fi "imagename eq setup.exe" |find ":" >nul
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto loop
echo Done.
echo.
IF %target%==%target% goto %target%

:NAVMAN
echo Installing Navisworks Manage 2020...
SET target=RECAP
START /WAIT %NavMansrc%\setup.exe /qb /I %NavMansrc%\AEC_2020_NavMan.ini
goto LOOP

:RECAP
echo Installing ReCap Pro 2020...
SET target=END
START /WAIT %Recapsrc%\setup.exe /qb /I %Recapsrc%\AEC_2020_ReCapPro.ini
goto LOOP

:END
echo Installation of AEC 2020 programs is completed...
echo
```

Comment: add `@echo off` as the very first line to suppress command repetition.